# MySQL data show nothing

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, phpmyadmin, encode

I insert Korean characters in mysql database.
But Data shows nothing. as well as in PhpMyAdmin.
Anyone know What problem is and How to solve?

The message said [Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'sido_id' at row 1]

```
create table sido (
        sido_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
        sido_name varchar(15) not null,
        primary key(sido_id)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;


insert into sido (sido_id,sido_name) values ('','서울');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdSaV.gif)

Comment: Dear Mr. Doe! According to the site rules you should [post the code, not pictures](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500)/screens of that.

Comment: Did you copy the Korean symbol right from the UTF8-charset symbol table?

Comment: It said there were Warnings.  Do `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after getting that message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asked as a series of images, three of which could be copy-pasted as code blocks

Comment: After the insert you see *1 row affected, 2 warnings*. What are the warnings? Use `show warnings` to see them.

Comment: I used Show warnings; The message said [Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'sido_id' at row 1] @Joni

Comment: The `id` should either be left out or specified as NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sido_Id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and data type is `INT()` and what are you doing? You are INSERT empty string in this column.

There is no need to use empty string for `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. You can use like that:

```
INSERT INTO sido (sido_name) VALUES  ('서울');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: @j-doe glad to help u... If it helps accept this answer

Comment: how to accept this answer? @devpro

Comment: @j-doe by click on the left tick